# Memory leak when using setState to overwrite value flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have some problem. When I try to overwrite a value using setState, infinite loop happening and a warning about memory leaks. I dont know why its happening, and I tried to put `if(mounted)`, but its still not working. Any advice for this?

```
    ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) => Divider(color: Colors.grey[400]),
      itemCount: listJadwalDokter.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          JadwalDokter jadwal = listJadwalDokter[index];
          if(jadwal.hari < now.weekday)
             for(int test = 0;test <jadwal.jadwalPraktek.length; test++) {
                cutiService.cekCuti(jadwal.kodeDokter + "." + listTanggalFormatKode[jadwal.hari + 7] + jadwal.jadwalPraktek[test].jam.substring(0, 2)).then((value) {
                     if (value)
                        if(mounted)
                          setState(() {
                               //when infinite loop happened
                             jadwal.jadwalPraktek[test].jam =jadwal.jadwalPraktek[test].jam.substring(0, 11) + "\n(Sedang Cuti)";
                          });
                 });
             }
       }
   )
```

This `ListView` is inside an `AlertDialog` that wrapped in `StatefullBuilder` so it can update the view when setState is called.

This is the error log

```
E/flutter ( 6791): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter ( 6791): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter ( 6791): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
```

Comment: I think the infinite loop is more concerning than a memory leak.  Is this code being called during a `build`?  If so, `setState` should not be called during a `build` because that would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: I see, so is it because setState called on variable declared inside `build` method instead of variable declared during `initState()`?

Comment: Changing the state causes a build.  Which in your case changes the state, which causes a build, which changes the state, etc. forever.  So you have to make sure you're not changing the state while in a build method.  Only change the state elsewhere.

Comment: I get your point, thank you for the explanation.